# Billing address request is not enabled for merchant

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal

Anyone knows where can I enable

"Billing address request is not enabled for merchant"

in sandbox environment?

Thanks
Darko

Answer (score 2):

Please open a [ticket](https://cn.paypal-techsupport.com/) to MTS technical team to help you on that.